# Cannot find cairo.h

Tags: r, conda, cairo

Common problem, but there's no solution for me so far - so maybe you can help a lost bioinformatician with rather little experience in IT stuff.
I need to install Cairo in my R environment (R version 4.1.1) on my mac Big Sur 11.5.1 and get this error:

```
> install.packages("Cairo")
...
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo... no
configure: CAIRO_LIBS is unset, attempting to guess it.
configure: CAIRO_CFLAGS=
checking if R was compiled with the RConn patch... no
checking cairo.h usability... no
checking cairo.h presence... no
checking for cairo.h... no
configure: error: Cannot find cairo.h! Please install cairo (http://www.cairographics.org/) and/or set CAIRO_CFLAGS/LIBS correspondingly.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing ‘/Users/thomaslordick/opt/anaconda3/envs/seurat4/lib/R/library/Cairo’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/48/5h26d5297_92l76cvyjqvk2h0000gp/T/RtmpD4g5aI/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warnmeldung:
In install.packages("Cairo") :
  installation of package ‘Cairo’ had non-zero exit status
```

I already installed `cairo-devel` via  `sudo port install cairo`, installed cairo via brew and also checked out similar threads (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-April/374096.html), where people recommend:

*Make sure you have cairo-devel installed, and remove the lines

export CAIRO_LIBS=${HOME}/usr/local/lib
export CAIRO_CFLAGS=${HOME}/usr/local/include

from your .bashrc file.*

I cant find a .bashrc file when using `ls -la ~/`... .

According to the above mentioned error I need to specify CAIRO_LIBS and CAIRO_CFLAGS. But where can I do this?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Do you have `cairo.h` installed on your system?  Where?

Comment: Yes. It's in my conda env: /Users/thomas/opt/anaconda3/envs/seurat4/include/cairo/cairo.h

Comment: I don't know conda, but I'd recommend using the standard Mac install of R.  Then you can install the Cairo package as a binary package, and not have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Conda for R environments, you are better off avoiding `install.packages` and instead make a point to always install through Conda. CRAN's `Cairo` package goes by `r-cairo` on Conda Forge. So,

```bash
conda install -n seurat4 -c conda-forge r-cairo
```

Comment: That actually worked for me! Thanks so much merv